# Proportions of character variables based on multiple variables and subgroups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, proportions

I have two columns in a dataset that represent meetings

| Occupation | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Director | M |
| Director | F |
| VP | M |
| Director | F |
| Secretary | F |
| Director | F |

So here we have 6 meetings, and these are the two proportions i'd like to obtain :

1 - Prop. of female director meetings / all the meetings (3/6)
2 - Prop. of female director meetings / meetings attended by women (3/4)

Of course i have thousands of observations.

I tried with the solution given here [How to calculate proportions from multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252337/how-to-calculate-proportions-from-multiple-variables) but i don't obtain the results that i want.

I'm pretty sure that is easy but i don't know how to take into account the "if" conditions. Also, i'd like to present the results through chart so it's better if the output is a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

`prop.table` takes a table object as input. This is what you get from a call that doesn't specify a margin (which I think answers your first question):

```
prop.table(table(dat[[1]],dat[[2]])) 
# could also be done on `table( dat$Occupation, dat$Gender)`
              
                 F         M     
   Director   0.5000000 0.1666667
   Secretary  0.1666667 0.0000000
   VP         0.0000000 0.1666667
```

And you probably also want row proportions, easily obtained by using  MARGIN of 1 (the R convention for rows).

```
prop.table(table(dat[[1]],dat[[2]]), 1)
             
               F       M     
   Director      0.75    0.25
   Secretary     1.00    0.00
   VP            0.00    1.00
```

#-----data construction -----

```
> TXT <- "
+ | Occupation| Gender|
+ | Director  | M     |
+ | Director  | F     |
+ | VP        | M     |
+ | Director  | F     |
+ | Secretary | F     |
+ | Director  | F     |"
> dat <- read.table(text=TXT, head=T,sep='|')[-c(1,4)]
> dat
   Occupation  Gender
1  Director    M     
2  Director    F     
3  VP          M     
4  Director    F     
5  Secretary   F     
6  Director    F
```

Comment: `table` takes a data frame, so here `table(dat)` would do. And I think `proportions` is the current name of `prop.table` ("an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility"). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik: Maybe if you have a package or a current version of R but I'm on R 3.6 and I get `?proportions
No documentation for ‘proportions’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??proportions’`

Comment: OK. `proportions` was introduced in `R 4.0.0`. "New function `proportions()` and `marginSums()`. These should replace the unfortunately named `prop.table()` and `margin.table()`. They are drop-in replacements, but also add named-margin functionality. The old function names are retained as aliases for back-compatibility."

Comment: I updated to R 4.1.0 and now see this revision. And now I can play with `|>` `<g>`